# getting Qpainter error while settext for qlineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, desktop-application

I am getting the below error while I am using setText for QlineEdit
(self.ui.Diode_ore.setText("Forward")) this is what I am using

`QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3 QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted`

because of this in ui I can't able to see full forward. and i am using thread to update the QlineEdit.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OkxP.png)

This what i am getting in the box f and w are visible.

I need solution for that problem. means the Line Edit Need to be update with full String

Comment: UI elements are not thread safe and must ***NEVER*** be accessed by external threads. Use QThread and custom signals.